# How to achieve the target in linux c as the java code do when I send a http post request to a server?

Tags: java, c, linux, http-post

There is  a java sample code below.It can send a http post request to a server with charset utf-8.How can I do the same thing in linux c program?

```
private String message = "3";
private String trading = "AAAAA";
private String document = "BBBBB";
private String targetURL = "http://10.1.2.3/param";

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(targetURL);

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("trading", partner));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("document", document));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("requestMessage", requestMsg));

HttpEntity request = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8");
httppost.setEntity(request);


HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String result = null;
if (entity != null) {
    result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
}
```

in Linux C, what http post request can achieve the same target as the java code dose?
eg.How to set the charset to utf-8
and: "message","trading","document" are in http post request's head or body?

These two questions really confuse me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to Java C doesn't come with a standard http client in its library (but then, you're using Commons HTTPClient in your Java example, also a third party library), so you have to select a third party library that implements this functionality.  There are dozens to choose from, from [quick and dirty](https://github.com/TheKirk/http-client-c) to the multiprotocol all singing and dancing [libcURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).  On the libcURL site you'll even find a list of their [competitors](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html) aka alternatives.

Which one is "best"?  That depends largely on what you find important, but libcURL is well documented, and comes with [a load of examples](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) - [this one especially](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html) as it's very close to what you want.  Due to its  popularity it will also eb a lot easier to find help in case of trouble.  It even has [its own tag here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libcurl)

Comment: I sent a http post request via libcurl. I use libcurl function curl_slist_append . The code is below:

Comment: char        *buf = "message=3:partner=\"aaaaa\":document=\"bbbbb\"";
    struct curl_slist *headerlist=NULL;

    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, ip_addr);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, requestMsg);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, strlen(requestMsg));
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

Comment: But I just got a wrong answer.HTTP/1.0 999 IMPERVA WAF. I'm stopped by the firewall?

Comment: Looks more like a web filter that filters outgoing traffic.  Check with your network administrator, he'll be able to help.